# Showing No Data message in React Chart js Line chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, linechart

How to show "No data available" message in react chart js line chart when there is no data available

```js
 <Line

                      chartData={{
                        labels: [],
                        datasets: [
                          {
                            id: 1,
                            label: 'Users',
                            data: dauData,
                            borderColor: '#86C6FF',
                            backgroundColor: '#86C6FF',
                            tension: 0.4, // disables bezier curves
                          },
                        ],
                      }}
                      options={{
                        plugins: {
                          legend: {
                            display: false,
                          },
                        },
                        
                      }}
                    />
```

Comment: With code. What have you tried?

Comment: code added, i could not find a prop or anything in documentation to show the no data message